# Whats the difference between Exception's .ToString() and .Message?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm looking through some code and I found e.ToString() and I was wondering if there is a difference to using the ToString() method instead of .Message ?

Reading below, it sounds like it returns more info.

[From Microsoft's Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx)

ToString
Supported by the .NET Compact Framework.
Overridden. Creates and returns a string representation of the current exception.

Message
Supported by the .NET Compact Framework.
Gets a message that describes the current exception.

Comment: I think you answered your own question

Comment: Exception is an object, using ToString on it, converts the object into a String ( which is an object ) so it would likely simply be equal to Namespace.Exception.

Comment: @Ramhound: `Exception` overrides `ToString`.

Comment: BTW, those are VS2003 docs; you should use newer versions. (click `Other Versions`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception.Message vs Exception.ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176707/exception-message-vs-exception-tostring)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're looking to get as much information as possible in one go, call `ToString()`:

> The default implementation of ToString obtains the name of the class that threw the current exception, **the message** *(my emphasis)*, the result of calling ToString on the inner exception, and the result of calling Environment.StackTrace. If any of these members is Nothing, its value is not included in the returned string.

It's convenient that you don't have to append all the individual elements together yourself, checking to make sure none are null, etc. It's all built in...

[Exception.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring.aspx)

You can also check out the actual source code at [reference.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,9ce1ff20e283169f).

Answer (score 12):

Try using .NET Reflector or similar to see what the ToString method on System.Exception is doing:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.ToString(true);
}

private string ToString(bool needFileLineInfo)
{
    string className;
    string message = this.Message;
    if ((message == null) || (message.Length <= 0))
    {
        className = this.GetClassName();
    }
    else
    {
        className = this.GetClassName() + ": " + message;
    }
    if (this._innerException != null)
    {
        className = className + " ---> " + this._innerException.ToString(needFileLineInfo) + Environment.NewLine + "   " + Environment.GetRuntimeResourceString("Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack");
    }
    string stackTrace = this.GetStackTrace(needFileLineInfo);
    if (stackTrace != null)
    {
        className = className + Environment.NewLine + stackTrace;
    }
    return className;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`ToString()` returns the `Message` along with the `StackTrace`.
`ToString()` will also recursively include `InnerException`s.

`ToString()` returns a much longer string which is much more useful than `Message` when tracking down errors.

Answer (score 4):

You could always just try it and see:

```
try 
{
  throw new Exception("This is a test.");
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex);
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

(You will find that you are correct, .ToString is more informative, including among other things the stack trace.

Comment: You should use this catch block instead : `catch ( Exception ex )
{
  Console.WriteLine("####RESULT OF TOSTRING ######");Console.WriteLine(ex);Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("####RESULT OF MESSAGE ######");;Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}`. This will help the OP to distinguish the output of both

Answer (score 1):

The `ToString` methods returns the `Message` property along with information on where the error occured.

The `Message` property is intended for a short description of the error, and only contains what the person implementing the Exception put there. The resport from `ToString` contains additional information that is always included.

If you are running in debug mode, the error report contains more detailed information, e.g. line numbers in the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

The e.ToString() will give you a detailed Message like PrintTrace i think which Display's the Exception Name and the Line where Exception was Thrown where e.Message Output's a Readable Message Only without Specification's.

You can check Exception base constructor