# how to pass argument in console application which having space using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application

I have a console file, which takes 6 arguments
[image]

I pass this argument using C# application, below code

```
try
{
    intializeConnections();
    string consolepath =    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsoleApp_backup"].ToString().Trim();
    // string backupPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBase_BackupPath"].ToString().Trim();
    string backupPath = @"D:\backup\Smart Tracker\";
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = consolepath;
    // proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(consolepath, Pc, database, UserName, Password, "F", bacPath);
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", serverName, DatabaseName, UserId, pw, "F",backupPath );
    //set the rest of the process settings
    proc.Start();

    clsGlobleFunction.InsertAuditTrailRecord_new(this.Name, "", "", "FullBackup Of Databse Done Sucessfull", clsGlobleFunction.ActiveUser);
    MessageBox.Show("FullBackup Done Successfully!!!!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "Give Correct Path in input !!");  
}
```

Its work perfectly,  but whenever i pass argument which have space in it, like in this code in backup Folder path, i am passing folder path **string backupPath = @"D:\backup\Smart Tracker\"**
so, its not working, console application consider space as a ending of argument,
and showing this error..
[image]

so, how can i pass argument which have space!!!!

Comment: As always: [Better use `Exception.ToString()` instead of `Exception.Message`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176707/exception-message-vs-exception-tostring) to get things like call stack.

Answer (score 4):

enclose your path within `single quotes` to consider the whole path as single string `argument`.

```
string backupPath = @"'D:\backup\Smart Tracker\'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulate the spaced argument in quotations.
I.E.  **@"\"D:\backup\Smart Tracker\"";**

Answer (score 0):

Try using Environment.CommandLine, you'll have to parse it or wrap in quotes.

Comment: Would you believe me if I said yes?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the path with `single single quotes ' '`

```
string backupPath = @"'D:\backup\Smart Tracker\'";
```

Or if you prefer:

```
string backupPath = @"\"D:\backup\Smart Tracker\"";
```

Comment: thanks for your attention, i try both but its not worked

Answer (score 0):

I try below code and its works perfectly !!!

```
 char c = Convert.ToChar(34);
 string backupPath = c + @"D:\backup\Smart Tracker" + c;
```