# Exception.Message V Exception.InnerException.Message

Tags: exception

I am currently logging errors and would like to get the most descriptive details possible.  I know I can catch many different types of exceptions but what is the difference between `Exception.Message` and `Exception.InnerException.Message`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176707/exception-message-vs-exception-tostring

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A program can catch an exception and re-raise a *different* exception, passing the original caught exception as the InnerException.  The `Exception(String, Exception)` constructor does this for example.  This happens in the .NET Framework itself, TypeInitializationException, TypeLoadException, TargetInvocationException, etc are raised this way.

The inner exception is *completely* unrelated to the raised exception and it is very, very important that you log the inner exception as well to have any hope of diagnosing the root cause of the problem.

The simplest way to do this is to use the ToString() method on the exception object.  Which provides the exception message, the stack trace and iterates through the inner exceptions.  Everything you need.

Comment: Now that makes sense to me! Far more info than I could have hoped for Thanks Hans.